# What is the distinction between a full node and a full public node?

Tags: iri-node

Further, are there a different set of system requirements between the two, and if so, what is it?

Comment: <comment removed> @Goooooose  If you have an answer, please post it in the 'answer' section below. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your reputation not the question please have a look at the [review queues.](https://iota.stackexchange.com/review)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A full public node is the same as a full node, but with external/remote access enabled. This means that other light wallet users, outside your local network, can use the node as well. Requirements are the same but a busy public node might experience more heavy load due to the extra requests from all light wallet users connected.

Comment: Is it possible to mitigate heavy load with higher specs on the public nodes or is it network bound?

Comment: I imagine it depends which bottleneck it hits first, which is dependent on the relevant server and network.